# What do the parentheses mean after INTEGER in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, integer

I see a sqlite statement that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dogs (dog_id INTEGER(4) PRIMARY KEY, dog_name VARCHAR(80))
```

What does the `INTEGER(4)` mean?

How big is that integer?

Thank you.

Comment: Would you like me to read the documentation for you ?

Comment: I tried reading the documentation, but I couldn't find anywhere where it mentions parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and does not put any limits on the values you can insert into a column.

For compatibility with other databases, you can specify one or two numbers in parentheses, but SQLite ignores them.